# Delay RES.REDIRECT Until Function(s) Have Completed? Or REFRESH Page when Complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to 'delay' res.redirect('/foo') until some functions have completed their tasks and I need your help please.

The /foo page is populated from a DB.  When the user has finished the transaction, I need to go process the records and then delete the records and finally 'reload' /foo against a now empty DB (ready for new input, so blank)

As it sits, /foo is loaded with the current data (if it would wait until doThis and thenThisCallback have finished, it would not have data to display which is what I'm trying for).

Can I do a "page refresh" from the last function when it completes?  Kinda like a location.reload() or window.location.href='/foo'.  (I tried and Node didn't like my attempts).

```
app.get('/foo/bar/:aparam', function(req, res) {
    doThis(a, thenThisCallback)

    // Dont redirect until 'thenThisCallback' is finished
    res.redirect('/foo');
})
```

I'd like to 'refresh' or redirect 'on demand' when my last function completes and I know the database is purged of expired data.  Currently, Node couldn't care less if my delete operation is finished :)

Maybe I could omit the res.redirect('/foo') in the route and do a GET call to /foo in the final function?  If that's possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the return value of the `doThis` function so it returns the callback function and that callback function to return a `Promise<void>`. Doing this, you can chain operation after that function has resolve.

```
// I'm not 100% sure about the parameters
const promisedCallback = (...params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        thenThisCallback(...params);
        resolve();
    });
};

app.get('/foo/bar/:aparam', function(req, res) {
    doThis(a, promisedCallback)
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/foo');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a delay to ensure, that every modification done in your db is completed before redirecting the user.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    res.redirect('/');
}, 1000);
```